# Database model for events with courses and races

Tags: database, database-design, model

I currently have the attached data model for a calendar and results database for ultrarunning events. My question revolves around how to best set up the tables and relationships for courses (all the different distances for an event) and races (an instance of an event using a particular course). My model site is [calendar.ultrarunning.com](http://calendar.ultrarunning.com/list), although I will build some features differently.[image]

### Tables

**EVENTS**
General info about a (usually) recurring event
- One event can have many courses (one-to-many)
- One event can have many races (one-to-many)

**COURSES**
All the info about a course, that an event can use (e.g. 50 miles, 50 km, 100 miles)
- One course can be used in many races (such as a 50 miles course in each year's race at an event)

**RACES**
A particular instance of an event, at a particular date, using one of the courses in the COURSES table.
- One race can have many (?) courses (this is one of the things I have a question about!!) - possible many-to-many with COURSES

**RESULTS**
Results for a particular race, including times, positions etc. for each runner.
- One race has many results 
- (OR an intermediary table related to COURSES and RACES, see question below)

**RUNNERS**
Info about each runner that participates at a race and gets a result.
- A runner can have many results

### Questions

Now what I'm thinking about is how to deal with dividing the data into COURSES and RACES.

1. I can choose a many-to-many relationship and let each race have many courses. That is, a race in this case is everything that is happening at an event on a particular date, including all the different distances/courses offered.
2. I can choose a one-to-many relationship and create one race for each course at an event on a particular date. That is, I have to create many races if there are many courses that year, rather than as in #1 where I only need one race with many courses.
3. I change to a completely hierarchical model, with RACES being child of COURSES. That is, for each race I select one (or many?) courses, which automatically connects the race to the event of that course.

**Scenario 1**:
In the case of #1, could I create an intermediary table - possibly containing the date - to which the results of that particular instance (a specific course on a particular date) is related? In this case, the date possibly has to be in both RACES and in this intermediary table? Or perhaps not in RACES?

**Scenario 2**:
In the case of #2, I would relate each result to one race in RACES and that race has only one course. Easy enough.

In scenario 1, the advantage could be that it is easier to create a race and I can have a description for whatever is unique to the event on that particular date.

In scenario 2, it will be more complicated to create let's say 4-5 different races for an instance of an event and those races have nothing in common but the date.

**Scenario 3**
With a completely hierarchical structure it's easy enough to understand the relations, as each race has one (or many?) course(s), which in turn belongs to an event. And the results are obviously connected to a race.

### Displays

The following are the displays that I am planning that are related to COURSES and RACES.
  a. List of all upcoming races, with the event name from EVENTS as the title, but with the distances from the COURSES table for each race from RACES on that date being displayed. 
  b. Upcoming and past races below the event details of the event page. 
  c. Detail page for a course, listing all upcoming and past races for that course. 
  d. Results page for an event. 
  e. Results page for a particular race instance. 
  f. Views with top results by gender and age group for a particular course. 
  g. Top lists (annual and all-time) for each distance, surface etc.

### Final question

Which approach to the relationships between COURSES, RACES and RESULTS is the best to accomplish this?

Comment: The relationship between courses, races and events is defined by your requirements.  You say "*for each race I select one (or many?) courses*".  Well which is it?  Do you have events with races that take place on many courses?  From a design perspective, we do not know, you or the client should establish that.  Another point, why link event with courses?  You can deduce that from races.  Events have races, races have course(s).  No need to link events and courses.  Unless you want to know of courses that are not used in races, but linked to an event...?  This breaks normal forms.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500
1) Regarding events with races that take place on many courses. Yes, that is often the case. But the question is if that should be regarded as one race with many courses or many races, even though it's usually regarded as simply a race with multiple distances to choose from. Which one I decide on is mainly a technical thing, whichever of t he two is easier to work with on the back-end.

Comment: 2) Why link event with courses? Main reason being to be able to deduct historical course results and course records. That is, a course can be (re-)used every year, whereas a race is only on one date. In my world the hierarchy would rather be event->courses->races. That is, an event has many courses that can be used for many (usually annual) races. Although every course that belongs to an event isn't necessarily used for each annual occasion of the event (the annual occasion of an event could be called a race, or many races, depending on the choice in #1 in the comment above).